# How to add space between <div>s in DataTables?

Tags: datatables

There's a very nice [CSS hack](https://kristinlbradley.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/cross-browser-css-justified-block-list/) to distribute any markup elements without applying static widths to the elements *or* the container, thus making the resulting elements still distributed if the size of the container is changed. This is based on `text-align: justify;`, which requires whitespace ([anonymous blocks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)) between elements.

I'd like to use this CSS for the DataTables controls, but the `sDom` initialization parameter ([1](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dom_multiple_elements.html), [2](http://datatables.net/usage/options)) doesn't seem to support any way to include whitespace between the elements. Does anyone know whether this is possible without a JavaScript hack?